# Gender-neutral term for a Senator or Representative

Tags: united-states, congress, terminology

Is there a gender-neutral term for a Senator or Representative?

- Senator: gender-neutral, but only includes Senators
- Representative: gender-neutral, but only includes Representatives
- Congressman: male-only, seems to be mostly used for Representatives
- Congresswoman: female-only, seems to be mostly used for Representatives
- Congressperson: gender-neutral, same problem as Congressman and Congresswoman
- Member of Congress: makes the most sense to me, but I've never heard it before

Comment: Member of Congress is commonly used to describe a Senator or a Representative. See [congress.gov](https://www.congress.gov/members).

Comment: @Panda thank you! It appears to be much more common than I had realized. Would you mind posting that as an answer?

Comment: Congressperson is the correct term. If it mainly is used for representatives, that is probably because there are more than four times as many of them.

Comment: Since you can't be a member of the House and the Senate at the same time, why are Senator and Representative being specific to senators and representatives problematic? The only issue I can see is if you need to identify more than one person, with a mix from both houses - "members of Congress."

Comment: @PoloHoleSet yes, it's to refer to either.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet or when the information of which house they're member(s) of isn't relevant in the context.
Also, the reason Congress(wo)man/person isn't used for Senators is also that being senator carries a bit more prestige as being a rep. It's *sort of* the same reason why you don't call a general "soldier".

Comment: The question literally means - 1) **Is** there a gender-neutral term for a Senator?, **or** 2) **Is** there a gender-neutral term for a Representative? Didn't you already have the answers which were listed under the question?

Comment: @r13 i meant "Is there a gender-neutral term that includes both Senators and Representatives?"

Comment: Understood. Why not edit and add the word "both" to it? This is a suggestion only.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Member of Congress is commonly used to describe a Senator or a Representative. See [congress.gov](https://www.congress.gov/members).

"Congressperson" is also a correct term. If it is mainly used for representatives, that is probably because there are more than four times as many of them. Also being a Senator carries a bit more prestige than being a Representative. It's sort of the same reason why you don't call a general "soldier".

Comment: convert comments to a CW

Answer (score 4):

A technical gender-neutral and cameral-neutral term is “legislator”.

> a person who makes laws; a member of a legislative body.

The more popular synonym, especially in media, is “lawmaker”.

Here are a few examples of headlines, just in the last couple of days, using the term lawmaker:

[image: Screenshot of search results for news with the word”lawmaker”]

Note that neither term refers uniquely to members of the United States Congress. They can be used to refer to a member of any legislative body. But, then again, the terms “senator” and “representative” are also not unique to the United States Congress.